# Facebook login doesn't work on Firefox only

Tags: javascript, facebook-login

I was using Facebook login in my website until I received some issues about it not working properly on Firefox. I'm testing on Firefox 55.0.3(64-bit).

To debug it properly, I've create a new blank index page, just like this:

```
<script>
    window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
        FB.init({
            appId: 'mypersonalID',
            cookie: true,
            xfbml: true,
            version: 'v2.8'
        });
        FB.AppEvents.logPageView();
    };

    (function (d, s, id) {
        var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) { return; }
        js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
        js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/pt_BR/sdk.js";
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

    function myClick() {
        console.log('click');
        FB.getLoginStatus(function (response) {
            console.log(response);
        });
    }
</script>

<button onclick="myClick()">Debug</button>
```

When testing it on Chrome, Edge, Explorer, etc.. The console is printing properly, however, on Firefox, I just see the console `click` but never the response from the Facebook event, also, I'm getting no errors at all.

I don't know what may be happening, but this just doesn't work on Firefox.

If I call FB.login() the popup shows up, but on cancel or confirm the login, the view just turns white and never closes or return the promise.

---

Edit: I tried to run it on Firefox Private mode and now I can see this error:

> The feature at "http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js" has been blocked because tracing protection is enabled.

Put still don't know how to solve this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a feature that is unique to Firefox. You can find information on how to disable this feature in private mode here:

https://blog.mozilla.org/futurereleases/2015/09/23/help-test-private-browsing-with-tracking-protection-in-firefox-beta/

You can also read up more on Firefox tracking protection and how it can break websites here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Firefox/Privacy/Tracking_Protection

Comment: So, it means there is no way I can solve this? Because I'm used to use other websites, such as Airbnb and news portal and it never happened before.

Comment: Just disable the feature in Firefox

Comment: But I'll be doing it in my computer only. What about the other users who will go to my website and try to use this service? It will be broken if they didn't disable it too. This is what I want to avoid.

Comment: Maybe you could use browser detect to notify people using Firefox to disable that setting in their browser

Comment: Or could tell Firefox users to use a different browser to access the site

Comment: I would also contact Facebook about the issue since they ultimately need to make their code Firefox compatible